# How do people usually implement multilanguage in Silverlight/XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, multilingual

I'm trying to implement an interface to offer multilanguage support. For the sake simplicity, I will pose an example in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="Type" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

I would wish to make the property "Text" of that XAML code to change depending on a variable which defines a language and an array on pairs  which returns, given a key, the associated text in that language.

Which would be the most practical way to implement that? Right now I use a property for each and every textblock defining the above Textblock in the following way:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

and then define a property like this one:

```
public string Type
{
     get
     {
        return Dictionary.Search("German", "Type");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localisation in Silverlight is generally approached with the use of [Resource Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and their hierarchical organisation in respect of region and culture. Runtime interprets those based on [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture%28v=vs.95%29), but this behaviour can be modified to meet your needs.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc838238%28VS.95%29) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650657.aspx) for starting point on [localisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You would use a tool like [Zeta resource editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) to create (and edit) resources for your default language and every supported language as well. Resources have to be named like `strings.resx`, `strings.en.resx`, `strings.de.resx` a.s.o.

When you add those resources to your project, a resource manager will take care of the correct language. You can then bind to the strings from XAML or use the class ResourceManager to get strings from code behind.

It is described in some detail here [How to: Make XAML Content Localizable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to maintain ResourceFiles for every language,It will automatically change text depending on current language when binded.

Comment: put this as a comment